# How to pass this step using the squezee theorem?

Tags: limits

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{ a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_k^n }$, $a_i >0$, $i = 1,2,...,k$

Let $a = max(a_1, a_2, ..., a_k)$

Then we have

$a\le\sqrt[n]{ a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_k^n }\le a \sqrt[n]{k}$

How did we get $\sqrt[n]{k}$ i know that there are k elements under the root but i can't grasp how we get then n-th root ?

P.S. Thanks for all the help, i know i worded the question really bad its my first time here if someone could point out how to form these types of questions so i know later on.

Comment: Suppose that $a_i=a, \: \forall 1\leq i \leq k$, i.e., all $a_i$'s are equal, hence maximum.

Comment: @Arash So when i sum them under the root i get $\sqrt[n]{k a^n} = \sqrt[n]{k} a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $a_i\le a$ by definition of $a$. If you now take the sum $a_1^n+\cdots +a_k^n$ we find the same inequality $k$ times:
$$a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n\le a^n+\cdots +a^n=ka^n$$
Taking the $n$-th root on both sides, we get
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n}\le \sqrt[n]{a^n+\cdots +a^n}=\sqrt[n]{ka^n}=a\cdot \sqrt[n]{k}.$$